# Is the OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credential Grant secured when using with my own spa?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a SPA (angular) with a back-end api (asp.net core), both are build and belong to the same party.

I would like to use jwt authentication instead of cookie based authentication, because both sides - the back-end and the front-end spa - are owned by the same party I'm thinking to use the OAuth Resource Owner Password Grant flow and there shouldn't be any problem exposing the users credentials to the web app.

After searching on the web, I see a lot that it's not recommended to use this flow, but why should I implement any OpenId Connect flow with a redirection to the auth server if the web client belongs to same party of the api and the auth server?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your case is not so much in exposing the credentials to the Client since as you mention, all components in the flow are controlled by the same party.

Yet there are advantages to redirection as doing so separates the authentication method and means from the Client itself. And that enables e.g.:

- a change of authentication mechanism or an upgrade to multi-factor (or some other advanced form of) authentication without impacting the Client(s)
- SSO across different web applications
- granular per-Client permissions
- easy access revocation without having to change the user's password
- less confusion for end-users as to which applications(s)/Client(s) they can trust with their credentials

Comment: Hans, Thanks for your response.